# Distribution of a sequence obtained from a simple stochastic process

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following program:

```
function x = getx(x = 0, p = .5)
  if rand > p
    x = getx(x)+1;
  else
    x = 0;
  end
end

for i=1:n
  z(i) = getx();
end
```

What is the distribution of $z$ ?

Comment: Do you know what the probability that rand>p is? That should make it easy to compute the distribution of getx. z is just a vector of $n$ independent variables with that distribution (independent assuming Matlab's random number generator is good, anyway).

Comment: rand is uniform distribution.

Comment: Yes, so rand>p holds with probability what?